# When there's 'at present' in the sentence, does it still need 'is doing' form?

Tags: expressions, present-perfect

An example:

I'm pleased to tell you that our company ___ rapidly at present.

What's the correct form? 'Is expanding' or 'expands'?

Answer (score 2):

Both may be technically correct, but the addition of "at present" makes "is expanding" the correct choice here. If you remove this part you're left with:

I'm pleased to tell you that our company is expanding rapidly.
or
I'm pleased to tell you that our company expands rapidly.

In the second case, our company might not be expanding at present, but when it does expand, it does so rapidly. In the first case, our company is definitely expanding at present. This makes "at present" redundant, but this is fairly common in the type of setting in which you would encounter this sentence.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm pleased to tell you that our company **is expanding** rapidly at present.

I would use "is expanding", because *at present* adds an indication of uncertainty regarding the future.
If you didn't want to say that, then I would leave out the "at present".

> > I'm pleased to tell you that our company **is expanding** rapidly.

Answer (score 0):

Both are correct

> I'm pleased to tell you that our company *is expanding* rapidly at present.
>   I'm pleased to tell you that our company *expands* rapidly at present.

meaning the company is growing quickly.

However, the first may be more common.